# Get more than one or all properties combining SELECT, COUNT, ORDERBY

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have this Query in Laravel:

```
$filmxlanguages =DB::table('films')
                ->join('languages', 'languages.id', '=", 'films.language_id')
                ->select('languages.language', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->orderBy('languages.language')
                ->get();
```

And it works perfect giving back the name of the language (languages.languages and the total of films pro language) in a simple table like this

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Number of films</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach ($filmxlanguage as $language)
      <tr>
         <td> {{ $language->language}}</td>
         <td> {{ $language->total}}</td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to hold another properties to add a column to my table like: language->image and to add a link using a slug that I have in the database like

```
<td> <a href ="{{ route('language.show', $language->slug)}}">{{ $language->language}}</a></td>
```

I added the two properties to the Select without success like that:

```
$filmxlanguages =DB::table('films')
                ->join('languages', 'languages.id', '=", 'films.language_id')
                ->select('language.slug', language.image', 'languages.language', 
                  DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->orderBy('languages.language')
                ->get();
```

How does it get more than one or all properties in Laravel using SELECT and COUNT?

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code to this:

```
$filmsxlanguage = DB::table('films')
    ->join('languages', 'languages.id', '=', 'films.language_id')
    ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('languages.language')
    ->get();
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Remove `->select()` out of your query builder to get all columns by default.

If you want to keep aggregate function as a column like `total`, you can write `->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))`;

In addition, your query builder  miss an apostrophe at `language.image`. It should be like that:

```
$filmxlanguages =DB::table('films')
            ->join('languages', 'languages.id', '=", 'films.language_id')
            ->select('language.slug', 'language.image', 'languages.language', 
              DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->orderBy('languages.language')
            ->get();
```

**UPDATE**
I think the real problem is not in select(). It may be related to the `SQL_MOD`.
Check your `app/config.php` in the `sql` part, try to change `'strict'=>false/true`
Please see here for more information [github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997](http://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997)

Comment: I need the total in order to use it in the front end. Therefore I used ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as total')); but it give back an error: QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mykino.films.id' isn't in GROUP BY...

Comment: I see you miss an apostrophe in you query builder, check it again then tell me.

Comment: No, it did not work. I have added the resulting code in an EDIT in the question

Comment: does it returns wrong collections or it does not run? post some var_dump or print_r result collections text here.

Comment: It does not work. It crash and give the QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mykino.films.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *, count(*) as total from 'films' inner join 'languages' on 'languages'.'id' = 'films'.'language_id' group by 'languages'.'language')

Comment: It looks so strange. I found here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997 Maybe you have problem with SQL_MODE. Check you `config/database.php`, inside the `mysql` config, change 'strict' => false/true

Comment: The answer was in that link you posted. I have edited my config/database.php file inside the mysql like:

'strict' => false,

Now it works fine

Comment: I had updated my answer, check it as an answer if you think so :D